# Adding a small icon to file icon

Tags: windows, file, icons

Some files sync apps like dropbox updates sync files icon on filesystem with a green checkmark icon (when the file sync is done) or a different icon when sync is in progress...Any idea how it's been done ?

Comment: It's called a glyph, if that helps

Comment: Actually, it's called an icon overlay. An article on doing this is [at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects) - it just happens to be C++ (ATL) as well.

Comment: Hmmm, where did I get glyph from then?!

Comment: You mean extract drop boxes? Or how to make your own. If you want to extract drop boxes, then this doesn't belong on SO. Anyways, it's In a DLL